# how do I create dictionary of dictionaries in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dictionary

In python, a dictionary of dictionaries can be created

```
  mainDict = {}
  mainDict[subDict][subDict_Key1]=[subDict_value1]
```

I want to create a similar dictionary of dictionaries or array of dictionaries in Javascript.
I have check multiple threads on SO but yet to find anyone.
I don't know the dictionaries yet, they will be added dynamically. For example I want to be able to create

```
var mainDict = {}
```

and then be able to add dict1,2,3... below

```
Dict1 = {name: sam, age:26, city:NY}
```

to mainDict so that I can iterate through mainDict and retrieve all dictionary with their respective keys and values

how do I do this in Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to *create* the "sub-dictionary" before assigning values to it:

```js
var mainDict = {}
mainDict[subDict] = {} // This was missing
mainDict[subDict][subDict_key1] = subDict_value1
```

Of course, if the values are static, this can be done in a more concise way:

```js
var mainDict = {
  dict1: {
    name: 'sam',
    age: 26,
    city: 'NY'
  },
  dict2: {
    name: 'joe',
    age: 27,
    city: 'LA'
  }
}

console.log(mainDict.dict2.name) // joe
```

Then you can iterate through the inner dictionaries as you wish:

```js
for (const key in mainDict) {
  console.log(`${key} has name ${mainDict[key].name}`)
}
```

...or, alternatively:

```js
for (const [key, subDict] of Object.entries(mainDict)) {
  console.log(`${key} has name ${subDict.name}`)
}
```